# e.preventDefault unstable and is not preventing the default action

Tags: jquery, events, preventdefault

I am trying to make the links not do the default action as going to the link, instead when user clicks the link it does the rest of the code which, in this case loads the appropriate url elements that I am calling with AJAX and place them in the correct Divs/span. Here is the code...

```
 $(function(){
    $('body').append('<span id="view_mess">New Message</span><div id="mess_wrapper"><div id="new_mess_pop"><div id="button_wrap"><span id="post_date_time"></span><div id="users_contact_info"><div id="users_image"></div><div id="message_lister"></div></div><div id="message_post"></div><div id="inner_mess_wrapper"></div></div></div></div>');
      $('#message_lister').load('/privmsg?folder=inbox .tdtopics:lt(5)');
        $('#view_mess').click(function() {
      $('#mess_wrapper').show();
       });
 $('.topictitle').click(function(e) {
  var msg = $('.tdtopics a').attr('href');
   $.get(msg, function (data) {
     var elems = $(data);
      $('#post_date_time').append(elems.find('div.posthead h2'));
      $('#users_image').append(elems.find('.user-basic-info'));
      $('#message_post').append(elems.find('.entry-content'));
   }, 'html');
e.preventDefault();
  $('#mess_wrapper').show();
 });
```

I've tried `e.preventDefault();` where it is in the above code and right after the function code. Maybe I should write the e in the first function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try with this :
Two things :you missed the end bracket of function  and e.preventdefault shuld be in start of the event 



 $(function(){
    $('body').append('<span id="view_mess">New Message</span><div id="mess_wrapper"><div id="new_mess_pop"><div id="button_wrap"><span id="post_date_time"></span><div id="users_contact_info"><div id="users_image"></div><div id="message_lister"></div></div><div id="message_post"></div><div id="inner_mess_wrapper"></div></div></div></div>');
      $('#message_lister').load('/privmsg?folder=inbox .tdtopics:lt(5)');
        $('#view_mess').click(function() {
      $('#mess_wrapper').show();
       });
 $('.topictitle').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  var msg = $('.tdtopics a').attr('href');
   $.get(msg, function (data) {
     var elems = $(data);
      $('#post_date_time').append(elems.find('div.posthead h2'));
      $('#users_image').append(elems.find('.user-basic-info'));
      $('#message_post').append(elems.find('.entry-content'));
   }, 'html');
  $('#mess_wrapper').show();
 });


}
```

Comment: no I had the end bracket. there was more to the code, but nothing that would interfere so I did not post it. I tried it there as well, and it goes to the link.

Comment: have you moved  e.preventDefault(); to top of the function ?

Comment: even though its not working ...use event.stopPropagation(); right after prevent default  to stop the flow of further events  too ..

Comment: I have moved it. I guess the issue is I created the content dynamically :( This is my fault, I suppose I should have posted the entire script as this is the issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return false;
```

this will prevent default as well as it will prevent Propagation

Comment: where should I place this return false? after function(){ or where I have the preventDefault?

Comment: as for return , i guess it is better for  it to be at the end of the function

Comment: this did not work either. This is confusing me why it is not preventing the default action :/